# How to log in without code of any kind

Tags: unity, login

My wife doesn't want to have any kind of login on her unity. She wants it to go directly to her home directory, when she press the "on"-button without asking for any code to be typed. How do I make it do that ?

Comment: If you have an encrypted /home you can't do this.

Answer (score 4):

Goto the shutdown button at the top right and select `system preferences`. From there in images...

[image]

Unlock and see the settings here:

[image]

- This will NOT work with on an ecrypted home.
- Other users can log in by choosing `log out` when the system has booted.

And since this question got 3 of the same answers something extra...
When you enter `gconf-editor` in command line and go to...

[image]

this will turn the system of without any confirmation when you press the power button ;)

Answer (score 3):

Press the Ubuntu button (top-left)  and type and click on ***Login Screen***.Unlock it with your login password and choose "Log in as " and close the window. Next time you reboot, it'll take you in directly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

type account in dash and you should see a result like "Login Windows"  (i'm not sure because i use a different language) and from there you can set the autologin

Comment: Not `account` but `login screen` ;)